# Project Euler 40: directly calculate digits of Champernowne's constant

Tags: java, programming-challenge

I implemented [Project Euler problem 40](https://projecteuler.net/problem=40) in Java. It works correctly, producing the correct answer.

During the course of implementing this program, I wrote a method that directly calculates a digit of [Champernowne's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Champernowne_constant), as opposed to the obvious brute-force approach. While brute-force is fast, this method takes under 1ms. In terms of speed, this is good code.

However, the method has a lot of repetition that I would like to get rid of, but I am not sure how. This may be a case of different code structures having similar attributes (those inner `if` blocks) that are not able to be combined, or any such optimization would introduce so many other complexities that it makes the code less clear.

Notes:

1. This method is long, too long. If there is no way to simplify this, I will split it into multiple methods on the top-level `if` statements. I have it all in one method in the meantime while looking for a way to refactor the code to be more concise.
2. I could refactor it to have multiple `return` statements, and I know that everyone has their own preference on this. I implemented it this way (final return variable and exceptions) to *fail fast*. It cannot compile if I forget a code path, and the exceptions kill the program in case of a logic error.
3. This is written in Java 8, so pretty much any language feature is fair game (e.g. lambdas).

---

The code:

```
  private static int getDigit(int d) {
    /* This algorithm does the following:
     * 
     * 1. Based on the requested digit, find which group of digits it belongs
     * to. A digit group is determined by how many digits each number has: for
     * example, all two-digit numbers are part of the two-digit group.
     * 
     * 2. Find the number that contains the requested digit. This can be easily
     * calculated because the size of each group is well-defined, and since all
     * numbers in the group have the same number of digits, we can easily
     * calculate which number contains the requested digit.
     * 
     * 3. Get the offset of the digit inside the number. This may actually be
     * in the next number. If the offset is zero, it is at the end of the
     * calculated number. If the offset (actually a remainder) is positive,
     * count that many digits into the next number.
     */
    final int result;
    if (d < 1) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Argument [" + d + "] out of range [1-7,688,889]");
    }

    // Single digits are the first 9 values and take up 9 total digits (1 - 9).
    else if (d < 10) {
      result = d;
    }

    // Double digits are the next 90 values and take up 180 total digits (10 - 189).
    else if (d < 190) {
      int offset = d - 9;
      int number = offset / 2 + 9;
      int digit = offset % 2;
      if (digit == 0) {
        result = number % 10;
      }
      else if (digit == 1) {
        result = (number + 1) / 10;
      }
      else {
        throw new AssertionError(digit);
      }
    }

    // Triple digits are the next 900 values and take up 2,700 total digits (190 - 2,889).
    else if (d < 2_890) {
      int offset = d - 189;
      int number = offset / 3 + 99;
      int digit = offset % 3;
      if (digit == 0) {
        result = number % 10;
      }
      else if (digit == 1) {
        result = (number + 1) / 100;
      }
      else if (digit == 2) {
        result = ((number + 1) / 10) % 10;
      }
      else {
        throw new AssertionError(digit);
      }
    }

    // Quad digits are the next 9,000 values and take up 36,000 total digits (2,890 - 38,889).
    else if (d < 38_890) {
      int offset = d - 2_889;
      int number = offset / 4 + 999;
      int digit = offset % 4;
      if (digit == 0) {
        result = number % 10;
      }
      else if (digit == 1) {
        result = (number + 1) / 1_000;
      }
      else if (digit == 2) {
        result = ((number + 1) / 100) % 10;
      }
      else if (digit == 3) {
        result = ((number + 1) / 10) % 10;
      }
      else {
        throw new AssertionError(digit);
      }
    }

    // Five digits are the next 90,000 values and take up 450,000 total digits (38,890 - 488,889).
    else if (d < 488_890) {
      int offset = d - 38_889;
      int number = offset / 5 + 9_999;
      int digit = offset % 5;
      if (digit == 0) {
        result = number % 10;
      }
      else if (digit == 1) {
        result = ((number + 1) / 10_000) % 10;
      }
      else if (digit == 2) {
        result = ((number + 1) / 1_000) % 10;
      }
      else if (digit == 3) {
        result = ((number + 1) / 100) % 10;
      }
      else if (digit == 4) {
        result = ((number + 1) / 10) % 10;
      }
      else {
        throw new AssertionError(digit);
      }
    }

    // Six digits are the next 900,000 values and take up 7,200,000 total digits (488,890 - 7,688,889).
    else if (d < 7_688_890) {
      int offset = d - 488_889;
      int number = offset / 6 + 99_999;
      int digit = offset % 6;
      if (digit == 0) {
        result = number % 10;
      }
      else if (digit == 1) {
        result = ((number + 1) / 100_000) % 10;
      }
      else if (digit == 2) {
        result = ((number + 1) / 10_000) % 10;
      }
      else if (digit == 3) {
        result = ((number + 1) / 1_000) % 10;
      }
      else if (digit == 4) {
        result = ((number + 1) / 100) % 10;
      }
      else if (digit == 5) {
        result = ((number + 1) / 10) % 10;
      }
      else {
        throw new AssertionError(digit);
      }
    }

    else {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Argument [" + d + "] out of range [1-7,688,889]");
    }

    return result;
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

The boundaries of where the number of digits increases can be generated and looped over:

```
int n=0, nDigits;
for(nDigits=1; n < d; nDigits++){
    n+= nDigits*(pow10(nDigits)-pow10(nDigits-1));
}
```

`pow10(n)` is a helper function to create the nth power of 10.

The big if-else can also be simplified and generalized a bit:

```
  if (digit == 0) {
    number--;
    digit = nDigits;
  }

  result = ((number + 1) / pow10(nDigits-digit)) % 10;
```

Comment: The idea is on the right track, but I am having difficulty getting this to work. I will check back later once I have more time to work with this idea some more.